# Android MPAndroidChart xAxis.setValueFormatter throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: mpandroidchart

Good morning,

I'm struggling with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown when i'm inserting the row

xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter) (commented in code).

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bc = findViewById(R.id.chart);

        CaricaStorico cs = new CaricaStorico();
        try {
            cs.execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        List<BarEntry> turno1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<BarEntry> turno2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<BarEntry> turno3 = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] date = new String[100];
        boolean datiturno1 = false;
        boolean datiturno2 = false;
        boolean datiturno3 = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < storicoMacchina.size(); i++) {
            Storico st = storicoMacchina.get(i);
            System.out.println(st.getData() + " - " + st.getProduzione1() + " - " + st.getProduzione2() + " - " + st.getProduzione3());


            turno1.add(new BarEntry(i, st.getProduzione1()));
            turno2.add(new BarEntry(i, st.getProduzione2()));
            turno3.add(new BarEntry(i, st.getProduzione3()));
            if (st.getProduzione1() != 0) {
                datiturno1 = true;
            }
            if (st.getProduzione2() != 0) {
                datiturno2 = true;
            }
            if (st.getProduzione3() != 0) {
                datiturno3 = true;
            }
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(st.getData());
            String dataMese = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
            xLabels.add(dataMese);
        }

        ValueFormatter formatter = new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return xLabels.get((int) value);
            }
        };

        BarDataSet set1 = null;
        BarDataSet set2 = null;
        BarDataSet set3 = null;

        set1 = new BarDataSet(turno1, "Turno 1");
        set2 = new BarDataSet(turno2, "Turno 2");
        set3 = new BarDataSet(turno3, "Turno 3");
        System.out.println(datiturno1 + "," + datiturno2 + "," + datiturno3);

        float groupSpace = 0.04f;
        float barSpace = 0.02f;
        float barWidth = 0.3f;
        // set1.setColors(new int[] { R.color.red, R.color.red1, R.color.red2, R.color.red3 },MainActivity.this);
        set1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.turno1));
        set2.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.turno2));
        set3.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.turno3));
        BarData barData;
        if (datiturno3 == false) {
            barData = new BarData(set1, set2);
            groupSpace = 0.06f;
            barSpace = 0.02f;
            barWidth = 0.45f;

        } else {
            barData = new BarData(set1, set2, set3);
        }
        barData.setBarWidth(barWidth);
        bc.setData(barData);
        Description desc = new Description();
        desc.setText("Produzione ultima settimana");
        bc.setDescription(desc);
        bc.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace);

        XAxis xAxis = bc.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
        xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1);
        xAxis.setAxisMaximum(storicoMacchina.size());
       // xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
        bc.invalidate();

    }
```

without this line code is working fine except for the labels in xAxis that i'm trying to set with this line.

Anyone can help me to find what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help
**your text**

Answer (score 1):

I'have found workaround to solve my problem changing the code above with this

If anyone can explain me the reason value index differs from my xlabel, dataset size will be appreciated.

Thanks again

```
   public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            String label = "";
            if ((value >= 0) && (value <= xLabels.size() -1)) {
                label = xLabels.get((int) value);
            }
            return label;
        }
```

Comment: Values (the things you plot on the chart) and axis labels are totally separate entities and will generally not be the same size. You could have a chart with 1000 values and only 4 axis labels, or if you adjust the chart ranges to a wide axis range you could have 20 axis labels and only 2 values plotted.